# JAX-RS service on WebSphere 8.5 Injecting EJB3.0 Fails

Tags: websphere, ejb-3.0, jax-rs

I am trying to get an existing EJB to work in a newly implemented JAX-RS service.

My project is set up as follows

```
root
  ear
  ejb
  war
```

The following is legacy JAX-WS code that works fine inside the war project...

```
@WebService
public class MyService {
    @EJB
    MyEJBLocal local;
...
}
```

I added the following JAX-RS resource to the EJB project (Long story, haven't had time to test in war yet)...

```
@Stateless
@Path("test")
public class MyResource {
    @EJB
    MyEJBLocal local;

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getCount(){
        //int count = local.getCount();
        //TODO: remove below once above is working
    return String.valueOf(20);
    }
    ....
}
```

When I remove the comments I get a null pointer exception because local is null. I think this is due to a problem with JAX-RS getting EJB mappings because I tried creating the initial context and passing the JNDI name and it fails to find the name, so I am guessing that is what is happening here.

Is there a workaround besides using JAX-WS instead of JAX-RS?

Comment: I think that ejb's in a `.war` are not visible to other modules. I'm not sure though